# Deploying .net mvc app on windows iis but compile it on linux server

Tags: .net, linux, iis, model-view-controller, continuous-integration

This might be an unusual scenario, but

I have a linux server, And my project is a .net mvc app on gitlab, now I want to setup a ci/cd pipeline using this linux server to build this app, and finally deploy it on a windows iis server. Is it possible? Are there much better ways to perform this, I dont want to use Azure devops, or any saas, I have my own linux and windows server instances, Is it fine to build a ci/cd pipeline on the windows instance itself where i am hosting my app, will it cause any performace issues? Or should I take two windows instance one for ci/cd and one for hosting?

Thanks in advance

PS: I am new to .net technologies and havent tried to deploy a .net app on windows

Comment: Yes you can publish in a linux environment using `dotnet publish` with the platform switch `-a win-x64`

Comment: .net can be deployed on windows server. For other problems, you need to try it yourself. If you get any problems during the process, you can discuss them in there.